Using cloudwatch and slack transports for winston under Lambda environment
im running a service under Lambda containers as its easier for me to have a way to  easily run it as standalone server if needed because its the same Docker image. For lambda I include public.ecr.aws/awsguru/aws-lambda-adapter:0.8.4 and it gives me what I need. My service uses Winston to log stuff and I wrote Slack transport for errors (using slack webhooks) and Im using https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-cloudwatch for cloudwatch logs. Things I want to understand are:

on first invoke when lambda pulls new image or creates container, if result of first invoke is error (if i intentionally send bad request params) slack transport will send error only when that container is killed (aprox. 5mins after there are no new requests), if i try new requests slack transport will send them to slack
winston cloudwatch transport will not log any error to cloudwatch during container lifetime but will send them all after container is killed when lambda decide to do that

What I think the problem is is that lambda as soon as request is finished freezes code so this async request cannot be completed, but why does it happend when container shuts down, I can share my implementation and would appreciate help with this. Thanks!
